# Slack Integration Privacy Notice scrollable to the sides

Tags: bug, mobile-web, design

I'm using Google Chrome in Android 10.

After viewing a snackbar informing me of the new [Slack Integration Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy/integrations/slack/teams-basic-business), I noticed a design problem. You can see horizontal scrolling in the next two images:

[image]

[image]

Basically without scrolling to the sides one isn't able to read the text completely.